# Can I use array_filter() on a class array?

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I'm attempting to intercept and filter items out of a class set array, $this->_vars, in a stripped down version of Smarty (not my choice :| )

Here's what I've been attempting to use:

Class callback function

```
private function callback_check($var){
    if(!in_array($var['link_id'], $this->returned_array['items'])) return false;
    else return true;
}
```

And the array filter itself:

```
foreach($this->_vars['content']['documents'] as $group_key => $link_groups){
    array_filter($this->_vars['content']['documents'][$group_key]['links'], array(&$this, "callback_check"));
}
```

Now it does appear to be detecting which ones are in the array and which aren't, as I replaced the returns with prints to check. However, nothing is being removed from the array. Is there any way to do what I'm attempting, or have I missed something obvious?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you missed something obvious ;)

`array_filter()` does not filter the array in place, it returns a new, filtered array. Given your code snippet, you do not use the returned array. Try something like this:

```
foreach($this->_vars['content']['documents'] as $group_key => $link_groups){
    $filtered_array = array_filter($this->_vars['content']['documents'][$group_key]['links'], array(&$this, "callback_check"));
    $this->_vars['content']['documents'][$group_key]['links'] = $filtered_array;
}
```

Comment: *smacks head - 

I thought I must have missed something. Thanks muchly! :D